# Prove that if $ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$, then $ \lim_{x\to a}|f|(x)=|l|$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have two related questions:

1) Suppose that $ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$ and prove that $ \lim_{x\to a}|f|(x)=|l|$.
2) Find a function $f$ and a point $a$ such that $ \lim_{x\to a}|f|(x)$ exists but $ \lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not.

I don't know how to start this question, any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Note that by the reverse triangle inequality, we have $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$ and so $||f(x)|-|l|| \leq |f(x)-l|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that by the reverse triangle inequality, we have $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b|$.
So, let $\epsilon>0$, as $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta $ implies $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$. It follows that $$|x-a|<\delta\qquad \implies \qquad ||f(x)|-|l|| \leq |f(x)-l|<\epsilon$$ implying $$\lim_{x\to a}|f|(x)=\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)| =|l|.$$
For an example of function such that $\lim_{x\to a}|f|(x)$ exists but not $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$, you can take 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x\geq a\\ -1 &\text{if }x<a\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $g(x)=|x|$ is continuous, part (a) holds immediately, since

$\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=|\lim_{x\to a}f(x)|=|l|$.

For (b), you need a function whose absolutely value is continuous but without the absolute value it isn't.  This should be a hint that you should have a function that changes immediately from positive to negative, so that when you take the absolute value, it's always positive.